# How to best define nano & terminal colour scheme for light Windows terminals (cmd)?

Tags: terminal, windows, colors, nano

It has been a usual thing for me to log into my Debian servers via a Windows `cmd` terminal during daylight. This is why the terminal has white background and black text.

Now, when editing a file with `nano` on the server, or when listing files with `ls -a` the server will show me bright colors, like yellow which I cannot read on the white background.

I know there are a lot of scheme files in `/usr/share/nano` to define those colours for my editor and I could just change the entries here, e.g.:

```
# Strings.
color brightyellow ""(\\.|[^"])*"" "'(\\.|[^'])*'"
```

But I would have to do it for all schemes individually. And then, when I use a black terminal, I would have to change it again.

So, is there a way to let the server know that my terminal is in light mode and thus adjust the colours? This might also help to define colours in `~/bashrc` so my listings will show up nicely.

Comment: Note that there is no `-all` option for `ls`, there is only `-a` and `-l` which can be combined as `-al` but `-all` is just the same thing with the `-l` option given twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited the question.

Comment: Also looking for an answer, hopefully something better than a script to search & replace to switch from dark to light, but whatever works works. Did you find anything so far?

Comment: My solution is to use `micro` when in need of different colours.